# Mysql query in laravel gives syntax error while using show syntax

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have sql query as follows

```
show indexes from `users` where not Non_unique and Key_Name <> 'PRIMARY';
```

But when I write same query in laravel as follows .

```
$columns = DB::select(DB::raw(" SHOW INDEXES FROM $table WHERE NOT Non_unique and Key_Name <> PRIMARY "))->get();
```

It gives me the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'PRIMARY' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ' to wrap `primary`,so change

```
$columns = DB::select(DB::raw(" SHOW INDEXES FROM $table WHERE NOT Non_unique and Key_Name <> PRIMARY "))->get();
```

to

```
$columns = DB::select(DB::raw(" SHOW INDEXES FROM $table WHERE NOT Non_unique and Key_Name <> 'PRIMARY' "))->get();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about why this happens

Comment: Just compare it with your original query sql and you will find the reason